# Are rollups run by a single sequencer centralized from a censorship point of view?

Tags: rollups, l2

In other words, can sequencers censor txs on rollups such as Arbitrum or Optimism?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on whether there is a mechanism to bypass the centralized sequencer.

In Optimism (now called OP Mainnet) and other OP stack chains, one can transact on L2 by publishing transactions, called deposited transactions, on L1. Those transactions are automatically included immediately in the first L2 block without any help from the sequencer.

In Arbitrum One and other Orbit and AnyTrust chains, users can push transactions to the DelayedInbox. If the centralized sequencer does not pop the transaction from it to the main Inbox (which defines the transactions included on the L2) within 24 hours, the user can do it permissionlessly.

In those cases, users inherit the censorship resistance of the base layer, in this case Ethereum, if they get censored by the permissioned actor.

At the moment, not all rollups have a similar mechanism: notable examples are Starknet and Polygon zkEVM.

Comment: Short answer is "not forever." Arbitrum has had incidents when the sequencer goes down and then what happens https://dedaub.com/blog/arbitrum-sequencer-outage - in practice, most users and applications do not know how to bypass the sequencer, so in this case maybe the most tech sawwy users can get their txs in and out. Also not sure what happened with bridged assets and native assets.